# MySQL While loop throwing an error

Tags: mysql, sql, while-loop

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @count FROM `tableName` WHERE `id` = OLD.id;

WHILE @count > -1 DO
    SET @count = @count - 1;
    /* loop logic in here */
END WHILE;
```

I have this SQL but when I run it I get an error (SQL Syntax) that MySQL says is near the `WHILE @count > -1 DO SET @count = @count - 1;`. I've tried wrapping the while in a `BEGIN ... END;` block but that doesn't affect it at all.

Due to MySQL's brilliantly vague errors I can't work out what I've done wrong.

I'm sure it's very simple but it's late and I can't spot it for the life of me.

Comment: Isn't @count of type `table` instead of an int?  I think you want to use `select @count=count(*) from tableName...`

Comment: How do you run this code? From what I see it's supposed to be inside the trigger body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just run this code in mysql client command line. You can use compound statements in the body of Stored procedures/Functions or Triggers